# Get a sub-set of a Python dictionary for a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, like the one below:

```
[{'name':1, 'id':2, 'otherstuff':3}, {'name':2, 'id':3, 'otherstuff':1}, {'name':3, 'id':1, 'otherstuff':2}]
```

How do I extract only specific keys for each member into another list?

Trying to get this:

```
[{'name':1, 'id':2}, {'name':2, 'id':3}, {'name':3, 'id':1}]
```

Comment: How do you determine the "specific keys"?

Comment: I updated the example to make it more clear. Basically I a have bunch of different keys with their values for each member, but only trying to extract name and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise a list of keys you need:

```
keys = {'name', 'id'}
```

Extract your key-value pairs in a `list`/`dict` comprehension.

```
filtered_data = [{k : x[k] for k in x.keys() & keys} for x in data] # thanks, vaultah!
```

The `x.keys() & keys` bit would work only in python3.x, since `x.keys()` is returned as a `set`, and the intersection operation ensures that no `KeyError` is raised if you try accessing a key that does not exist in that particular sub-dict.

Comment: or `[{k: x[k] for k in x.keys() & keys} for x in data]`